# Understanding how keying works in payload creation

Tags: backdoor

I'm reading this article, https://www.mdsec.co.uk/2022/05/nighthawk-0-2-catch-us-if-you-can/

In the payload generation it has a keyring strategy. I couldn't understand what keying do here. Is the payload encrypted with this specific key? Or stashed in certain location?

The article didn't say much, does anyone know?

[image]